# GLSL: Are dynamically uniform expressions only calculated once?

Tags: opengl, glsl

If some calculations in a GLSL shader are only dependent on uniform variables, they could be calculated only once and used for every vertex/fragment. Is this really used in hardware? I got the idea after reading about "Uniform and Non-Uniform Control Flow" in the GLSL specification:

https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.4.40.pdf#page=30&zoom=auto,115.2,615.4

I would like to know if theres a difference between precalculating projection- and view-matrix for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the driver and the optimizations it is built to do, in direct3D there is an explicit api for that.

For example the simple point of

```
//...

uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 model;

main(){
    gl_position = projection*view*model*pos;
}
```

most drivers will be able to optimize it to precalculate the MVP matrix and pass just that in a single uniform.

This is implementation defined and some drivers are better at inlining uniforms than other. One other optimization option is recompiling the entire program with inlined uniforms and optimize non-taken paths out.